# Edit each line with TODO and write code based on the skills you learned. You'll want to use an if statement and addition

Tags: csv

```
require 'csv'

total_sales = 0

CSV.foreach('sales-data.csv', headers: true, converters: :all) do |row|
  # TODO: check if category is "Music" (row[2])
  # TODO: if it is music, add total_sales + the row's sales (row[6])
  if row[2] = "Music"
 total_sales + row[6]

end
```

puts total_sales.round(2)
   It keeps having error on puts total_sales.round(2)

Comment: For a start, what exactly do you think `total_sales + row[6]` will do? Secondly, if you *have* an error, it might be a good idea to *show* us the error. We're not psychic :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.